# What happens if I kill my teammate?

Tags: battlefield-3

What will happen if I kill one of my teammates in Battlefield 3?

I am afraid to play on the Hardcore difficulty because I will lose points if I kill my friend accidentally.

Will I lose points? Are there any other penalties?

Answer (score 5):

In BF3, you won't get punished for teamkills by the game itself, but some servers (at least on the PC) do warn/kick/ban teamkillers after a specific amount of kills.

Besides, why are you frightened of losing points? Even if you lose points like in BC2, you still need to kill more teammates then enemies to leave the game with a lower score than at the start of the round.

Comment: Yup occasionally I would destroy an objective building (bc2) where noobs inside wouldnt get out. And you could rack up -500 points. (even on non Hardcore). But by no means did that leave me with negative score. Its unlikely to happen, and even if it did, next server would make up for it. Getting Tks isnt easy unless you try to. You might occasionally shoot someone you shouldnt out of reaction. But if you say sorry, the game continues. You dont need to play hardcore anyway. Some people prefer not to. There is nothing to worry about either way. Try it and see how it goes.

Comment: I guess the two most common ways to TK - even in non-hardcore - is to destroy a building with teammates (camping) in it, as @Doomsknight mentioned, or if you are i.e. the pilot of a chopper and crash it to the ground while the gunner is still in it.

Comment: Consoles usually kick you after 5 teamkills I think. There is no point penalty.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.
i asked this because I know in BC2 and COD you lose point, there is a lot of stuped players get infront of you while you are shooting to an enemy

Comment: You're Welcome! Mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your team will lose a ticket just like any other cause of death.

Apart from that, it's +1 kill for you, just like any other kill, and vice-versa, +1 death for your team-mate.

If it wasn't deliberate, you just apologize by team-saying something like "Sorry for tk!*"
and move on.

It's not very uncommon to kill a team-mate on hard-core accidentally. Just don't do it repeatedly ;)

*tk: Teamkill.